# how can i test to see if a stream is the problem or is it my code?

Tags: android, stream, media-player

I'm trying to write this little app in my journey to learn android dev. it's supposed to open a static page just for something to look at while it plays a streaming internet radio program. the code executed with no crash or error, but i don't hear anything, so i am wondering if this is really the right path to stream. how can i know? it plays in the browser but not in the app. is there a way to know if your stream is really a stream and not an embedded media or something?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.somesite.com");

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://streamdb1web.securenetsystems.net/radio_player_large.cfm?stationCallSign=WPBRADIO&relocateURL=true");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the code executed with no crash or error

I presume by 'no crash' you mean there was no popup telling you there was a problem? Even so, are you sure there is no error? Have you checked the logcat data?

Assuming logcat doesn't show anything, the first thing I'd do is try a known url which works with something like WinAmp or Windows MP. Many Shoutcast streams are as simple as http://site:port and work fine with MediaPLayer.

On the flip-side of the above I'd try that URL in WinAmp or WMP.

Fairly simple checks - if that URL plays with something else then it's fine and your code is broken. If something else plays in your code then that URL is suspect.

Comment: i have tried two different attempts of what i think are streams. and i did indeed get an error in the log

03-03 22:12:57.709: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1767): start called in state 0

03-03 22:13:12.272: ERROR/QC-DSS-LIB(51): unrecognized ifindex 7

03-03 22:12:57.709: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1767): error (-38, 0)